How to create a calendar view in SPO with reduced column numbers
I wonder if this is possible. I've a SP list form with approx. 40 pieces (40 columns in the list) of information with need to be filled in when a new item is created. However only a small number of people need to see and be able to edit all these columns. For the majority of people, they only need to see approx. six (data from six columns) pieces of information. Is there any way to display this reduced number of columns in calendar format, while still having all 40 items visible on a 'New item' form. I can create this list view selecting only six columns, but can this be made into a calendar view?
Thanks for any help.

As far as I know, SharePoint's Calendar view can only show the values of a certain column, which by default is the Title column. You can't do it if you want to show the values of all six columns.But when we click on a specific time it will show all the columns.


This is designed by SharePoint and we can't change it.
